# How to provision an instance in OpenStack

Tags: openstack

I'm just starting to learn about OpenStack, and I'm trying to put together the puzzle pieces. One question that I cannot find a definitive answer for in the OpenStack documentation is how a typical machine provision works and what tools to use.

For example, I have Vagrants for Jenkins and Gitlab VMs and I want to recreate these Vagrants into something that I can actually run on OpenStack. Though there are various  tools for provisioning in general, though the bits and pieces that play together with OpenStack are currently a blackbox for me.

The documentation page about provisioning here an image which I do not find much helpful:
https://docs.openstack.org/operations-guide/ops-customize-provision-instance.html

And the components overview doesn't seem to contain a particular component for machine provisioning:
https://www.openstack.org/software/project-navigator/openstack-components#openstack-services

What provisioning tools do play nicely with OpenStack?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the `openstack` environment success, there are few commands will provision an simple instance:

```
source /etc/kolla/admin-openrc.sh
openstack image create --file cirros-0.4.0-x86_64-disk.img cirros-4.0
openstack flavor create --vcpus 2 --ram 4096 test.2C4G
openstack server create --flavor test.2C4G --image cirros-4.0 TEST.inst
```

because the usage of `openstack server create -h` will show that only three necessary arguments `(--image <image> | --volume <volume>), --flavor <flavor>, <server-name>`.

This documentation https://docs.openstack.org/operations-guide/ops-customize-provision-instance.html only show the `interaction of components when provisioning an instance on OpenStack`.

Maybe you should starting to learn about OpenStack from https://www.openstack.org/software/ , it show the all components on OpenStack, such as this architecture https://www.openstack.org/openstack-map .

IIUC, you want to deploy `Jenkins` and `Gitlab` service on `OpenStack`'s instance, in my opinion, you would like to learning the `zun` component and `magnum` component if you need.

But if you only want to deploy your `Jenkins` and `Gitlab` service, why not using `Docker` and `Kubernetes` ?

The last question `What provisioning tools do play nicely with OpenStack?`

If you want to quickly start some demos of `OpenStack`, you could using `kolla-ansible` tools to deploy OpenStack with `all-in-one` environment. And `Multinode` in your produce environment, check from https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/ , and **make sure what you do before deploy in production**.